# running apply (or variant) like an embedded loop

Tags: r, performance, apply, lapply

I'd like to do something like an embedded loop, but using apply functions, the goal of which is to check various conditions prior to moving on to the next part of my program.

I have two objects, a list of product descriptions, which can be created as follows:

```
test_products <- list(c("dingdong","small","affordable","polished"),c("wingding","medium","cheap","dull"),c("doodad","big","expensive","shiny"))
```

And a data frame of combinations of features that are not allowed, where each row represents a disallowed combination of features. A sample data frame can be created as follows:

```
disallowed <- data.frame(trait1 = c("dingdong","wingding","doodad"), 
                         trait2 = c("medium","big","big"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My goal is to check each product against each of the disallowed combinations as efficiently as possible. So far I can check one product against all prohibitions as follows (in this case, the third product):

```
apply(disallowed, 1, function(x) x %in% unlist(test_products[[3]]))
```

OR I can check all products against one of the disallowed combinations of traits (the third combination).

```
lapply(test_products, function(x) disallowed[3,] %in% x)
```

Is it possible to check all products against all rows of the data frame of disallowed feature combination, without using a loop?

My end result should look something like this:

```
Product 1: OK
Product 2: OK
Product 3: NOT OK
```

Since Product 3 runs afoul of the third disallowed row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely more elegant ways, but I am going to share my thoughts on this.

First, the way you created the `disallowed` data frame is convoluted. I decided to use the following code to create `disallowed`.

```
# Create a data frame showing disallowed traits
disallowed <- data.frame(trait1 = c("dingdong","wingding","doodad"), 
                         trait2 = c("medium","big","big"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I then created a function called `violate`, which has two arguments. The first argument `product` is a vector of character. The second argument, `check_df`, is the data frame contains disallowed traits.

The output of `violate` is a logical vector. `TRUE` means all two traits from the `check_df` of the row are both `TRUE`.

```
# Create the violate function
violate <- function(product, check_df){
  temp_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(check_df, function(Col) Col %in% product))
  temp_vec <- apply(temp_df, 1, function(Row) sum(Row) == 2)
  return(temp_vec)
}

# Test the violate function
violate(test_products[[3]], check_df = disallowed)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

After that, I applied the `violate` function using `sapply` through the `test_products` list. The results from `violate` were evaluated to see if all disallowed checks are `FALSE`

```
# Apply the violate function and check if all results from violate is FALSE
sapply(test_products, function(product){
  sum(violate(product, check_df = disallowed)) == 0})
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see, the third element of the results is `FALSE`, indicating that the third product is not OK, while product 1 and product 2 are OK because the final results from `sapply` are both `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks @ycw. You're right that my example was convoluted! And I'll be editing my question to use your modification. Will test your answer later today

Comment: Works great! Thank you.